# send objects in selector swift

Tags: ios, swift, selector

can you send multiple objects by clicking a button?

I am trying to call this function

```
 func getWeatherResults (lat: Double, long: Double{

}
```

by clicking a button created on viewFor to get coordinates from the annotation clicked

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    var **lat** = annotation.coordinate.latitude
    var **long** = annotation.coordinate.latitude

    guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else { return nil }

    let annotationIdentifier = "Identifier"
    var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?
    if let dequeuedAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier) {
        annotationView = dequeuedAnnotationView
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }
    else {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
        annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
    }

    if let annotationView = annotationView {
        annotationView.canShowCallout = true

        let smallSize = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)

        let krakenPinImg = UIImage(named: "kraken_ic")
        annotationView.image = krakenPinImg?.resizedImageWithinRect(rectSize: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: smallSize))
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "weatherWindyDarkGray"), for: UIControlState())
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getWeatherResults) for: .touchUpInside)
        annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button
    }


    return annotationView
}
```

thanks!

Comment: The only valid parameter to your `getWeatherResults` method is the button that triggered its call (yes, I know that's not quite true but close enough for this question).

Comment: send coordinate to it and then get `coordinate.latitude` and `coordinate.longitude`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't customize the parameters sent to a button's action. The only valid options (as covered in the documentation for `UIControl`) are to have parameters, the sender (the button in this case), or the sender and the event.

The proper solution is to store the coordinate in a property. Then you can access that property in the button handler as needed.

Add the property to your class:

```
var lastCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
```

Update your map view delegate method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    lastCoordinate = annotation.coordinate

    // and the rest of the code
}
```

And update your `getWeather` method:

```
func getWeatherResults() {
    if let lastCoordinate = lastCoordinate {
        let lat = lastCoordinate.latitude
        let lon = lastCoordinate.longitude
        // Use these values as needed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom class for your button. Like this:

```
class customButton: UIButton {
    var parameter : String?
}
```

Set type of your button as customButton and set the parameter:

```
button.parameter = ""
```

Comment: FYI - this is not a good solution. Subclassing `UIButton` every time you need to access data is a poor design. Views should not contain data. That violates standard model-view-controller design.

Comment: Thanks for clear my doubts! Now I know what I should use.